# StringIO and pystache generate spurious null bytes

Tags: python, mustache

I am parsing a mustache file into a string, and after that I want to process that string with the csv module. For that I generate a file like interface to the string using StringIO. The csv module is complaining with:

```
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

So I made a simple test:

```
import pystache
from cStringIO import StringIO

txt = pystache.render('Hello {{name}}', {'name' : 'Steve'})
f = StringIO(txt)
data = f.read()
print txt.find('\x00')
print data.find('\x00')
print txt.count('\x00')
print data.count('\x00')
```

Which produces:

```
-1
1
0
33
```

Somehow the StringIO object is inserting NULL bytes. This does not happen if I use a string which has not been pre-processed with pystache:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

txt = "Hello Steve"
f = StringIO(txt)
data = f.read()
print txt.find('\x00')
print data.find('\x00')
print txt.count('\x00')
print data.count('\x00')
```

The result is as expected:

```
-1
-1
0
0
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txt = "Hello Steve"` is a bytestring, could the preprocessed string be a unicode string?

Comment: Indeed it is. How can I use that with the StringIO module? Or, if that is not possible, how can I convert that to a normal bytestring?

Comment: I solved it. It was enough to add a `.encode('utf-8')` to `pystache.render('Hello {{name}}', {'name' : 'Steve'})`